# View columns from query

Tags: php

Get Item Function

```
//Wearing Character Function
function wear($id)
    {
        global $database;

        $stmt = $database->runDB("SELECT item_code,option1,option2,option3 FROM item_table WHERE player_id = ?");
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        var_dump($result);
        return $result;
    }
```

Restult must be 33,44,55,66 but instead of that i get only **bool(false)**

View Page

```
<?php $i=1; foreach($list as $player) { 
                                        $job = job_name($player['job']);
                                    ?>
    Player Name -  <?php print $player['player_name']); ?>
Player Job - <?php print $job; ?>
    Player Wear - <?php print wear($player['player_id']); ?>
<?php } else print $lang['no-chars']; ?>
```

how to print everything in viewpage ?

tried

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                {
                    echo $row['item_code'];
                    echo $row['option1'];
                    echo $row['option2'];
                    echo $row['option3'];
                }
```

Comment: Where is `$code` set in that function?

Comment: `bool(false)`, or simply `false`, means your query didn't work. See: [PDOStatement::fetch()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)